# Java HTTP/2 client implementations without ALPN

Tags: java, netty, okhttp, embedded-jetty, http2

There is a [list](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations) of Java HTTP/2 client implementations. I've found Jetty, Netty and OkHttp [code examples](https://github.com/fstab/http2-examples/tree/master/multiplexing-examples) and seems like they all need to include specific version of [ALPN library](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html) depending on jdk installed. I don't like it because it makes troubles when you are not the only developer on the project.

I need to query `https` urls. The question is: are there any HTTP/2 client implementations that don't use ALPN? Working code examples are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

OkHttp works without any special alpn-boot jars on Java 9 beta, this is automatic.  In future OkHttp could hopefully also support https://github.com/google/conscrypt.

I believe both Jetty and Netty support HTTP/2 prior knowledge (without NPN/ALPN).

e.g. Jetty

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/0c8273f2ca1f9bf2064cd9c4c939d2546443f759/jetty-http2/http2-http-client-transport/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/http2/client/http/DirectHTTP2OverTLSTest.java#L86

```
    HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2 transport = new HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2(new HTTP2Client());
    transport.setUseALPN(false);
    client = new HttpClient(transport, newSslContextFactory());
```

I believe for Netty it works if you use HttpToHttp2ConnectionHandler